# Detecting Windows settings (scaling text and items)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know if it is possible to detect if Windows is set to:
"Make text  and other items larger or smaller" settings other than "100%"?

I'm working in Visual Studio and coding in C#. Would be great if there is a class with a function that could return the information so that I can scale my application accordingly.

Regards,
Jonas

Comment: Sure, Graphics.DpiX/Y in Winforms, PresentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11/M22 in WPF.  You need to use proper [tags] when you ask a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the actual screen width and height after scaling with "Make text and other items larger or smaller":

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

Then you can scale your application accordingly.

Comment: For future searches: You'll need to add a reference to your Visual Studio project, 'Presentation Framework'. (It's the vanilla one, NOT any of the others with extensions such as 'Presentation Framework.Aero'.